# Prepend text to console output

Tags: r

In various R books including *[R for Data Science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/introduction.html)*, the console output is modified such that it looks like this:

```
1 + 2
#> [1] 3
```

instead of the default:

```
> 1 + 2
[1] 3
```

The niceness of this is that one can directly copy the code and output into one's own R session/script and run it without issues. The code works because the default `>` and `+` characters have been removed, and the output causes no trouble because it has been out-commented.

There's a questions on SO about fixing the first line (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448600/change-default-prompt-and-output-line-prefix-in-r)), i.e. setting options to something like this `options(prompt = " ", continue = "     ")` (the second fixes the multi-line input situation). However, I was unable to find any way to prepend `#>` to the output. Can this be done in regular session or is it limited to **knitr**/**rmarkdown**?

Comment: The [reprex](https://github.com/tidyverse/reprex) package helps to make code formatted in this manor. I assume you want to change the output so you can copy/paste it elsewhere; this will help with that.

Comment: I had in mind just changing it permanently for console output, not only for specific examples, but I agree that **reprex** package is useful for this purpose.

Comment: Try `options(prompt="#>")`. You can also put this in your `.Rprofile` to make it default.

Comment: No, that does not change the output, which is what this question is about.

Comment: Ah. Sorry. I misunderstood your question.